# How to create a cfcollection / verity collection with a UTF-8 character in the name?

Tags: utf-8, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, verity

I'd just like to be able to use a UTF-8 character in the name of the collection.  We base our code logic on the names of the collections which are related to a given company.  This new company has an abbreviation of XØZ3, and both the CFAdminstrator and cfcollection seem to have issues with using the ø in the collection name.

The errors presented are:

```
Unable to create collection peoplexscvdocsXØZ3.
Unable to create collection peoplexscvdocsxøz3.
An error occurred while creating the collection: com.verity.api.administration.ConfigurationException: Fail to create the index. (-6220)
```

Comment: Verity's kinda obsolete after CF 9.0.1 (it was removed in 9.0.2 altogether), and doesn't actually exist as a product any more. I'd say you're stuck with what you have, and if it doesn't work, then... well: it doesn't work. That aside, it's not so helpful simply saying "seems to have issues". What are they issues? Don't leave it for us to guess.

Comment: updated the question.  @AdamCameron while I'm aware it's obsolete, and not an ideal solution, I'm here looking for assistance with an existing infrastructure, not an idealized one.

Comment: My point was more that you're unlikely to be able to fix this situation @ Verity level, you'll just need to approach it a different way. Probably convert the name you're using to just be printable ASCII chars rather than trying to get Verity to accept unicode here.

Comment: There are a number of matches on Google for that error message. Have you been through them all and ruled them out as a solution / guidance / explanation?

Answer (score 1):

If verity doesn't accept UTF-8 and there isn't a work around, I guess you'll have to

- have 2 fields, one with ascii based version of the character, one with the html/xml version of the character
- pass through the ascii version of the characters when searching the collection to match

so you'd have:

plaintext: XOZ3

XMLText: X`&#216`Z3;

And a function that takes **Ø** and changes it to **O** when searching verity on the `plaintext` field and return the matching `XMLText` field